# Deploying Cloud Function with GitHub Actions requiring build to happen prior to workflow

Tags: google-cloud-functions, github-actions, continuous-deployment

I'm using GitHub Actions to deploy my Cloud Functions.  I thought my process was working fine until I noticed the local "build" folder was being included in the commits.  I removed that and, when I did, deployments started to fail.  My workflows include the same build script that is used locally but the deployment fails saying build/src/index.js is not found.

When the local `build` folder is included in the commit, the deployment works fine.

When the local `build` folder is removed from the commit, the deployment fails, even though the workflow performs a build prior to running deploy command.

I noticed I couldn't find examples of people doing their build in the workflow.  Shouldn't this work?

*.github/workflows/cicd-dev.yaml*

```yaml
name: 'Deploy Cloud Function to DEV'

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - 'dev'

jobs:
  deploy:
    runs-on: 'ubuntu-latest'

    steps:
      - uses: 'actions/checkout@v3'

      - uses: 'char0n/swagger-editor-validate@v1'
        with:
          definition-file: 'openapi.yaml'

      - uses: 'actions/setup-node@v2'
        with:
          node-version: '20'

      - run: 'yarn install'

      - run: 'yarn test:ci'

      - run: 'yarn build:dev'

      - uses: 'google-github-actions/auth@v2'
        with:
          credentials_json: ${{ secrets.GCP_CREDENTIALS_CICD_DEVELOPMENT }}

      - uses: 'google-github-actions/setup-gcloud@v2'

      - run: >
          gcloud
          functions
          deploy
          pubsub-api-ms
          --set-env-vars=NODE_ENV=development
          --region=us-central1
          --source=.
          --runtime=nodejs20
          --gen2
          --trigger-http
          --allow-unauthenticated
          --entry-point=pubsubApiMs
```

*package.json*

```json
{
  "name": "pubsub-api-ms",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "main": "build/src/index.js",
  "license": "UNLICENSED",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "stop:emulator": "lsof -t -i:8080 | xargs kill -9",
    "start:emulator": "functions-framework --source=build/src --target=pubsubApiMs --port=8080",
    "start:local": "npm-run-all stop:emulator build:tsc start:emulator",
    "test:ci": "jest",
    "build:clean": "gts clean",
    "build:tsc": "tsc",
    "build:dev": "npm-run-all build:clean build:tsc",
    "run:local": "nodemon --watch ./src -e ts -x \"yarn start:local\""
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@google-cloud/functions-framework": "^3.3.0",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "express": "^4.18.2",
    "helmet": "^7.1.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/cors": "^2.8.17",
    "@types/express": "^4.17.21",
    "@types/helmet": "^4.0.0",
    "@types/jest": "^29.5.11",
    "@types/node": "^20.11.5",
    "gts": "^5.2.0",
    "jest": "^29.7.0",
    "nodemon": "^3.0.3",
    "npm-run-all": "^4.1.5",
    "ts-jest": "^29.1.1",
    "ts-node": "^10.9.2",
    "typescript": "^5.3.3"
  }
}
```